ONNX model pooling layer converter does not support attribute called dilations
I encountered an error while trying to use the ML model from the multi-object notebook that is provided from SnapChat, when I import the ML model There is an error:
"Resource import for D:/Downloads/best (6).onnx failed: Exception at layer '/model.8/m/MaxPool': ONNX model pooling layer converter does not support attribute called dilations",
I'm not sure on how to fix it and what the problem is since it was working perfectly fine before. Thank you!
Error
I have tried to use other notebooks for conversion to .onnx model but nothing seems to work
